# Why dialog position shows a small displacement?

Tags: android, kotlin

From the click on a  button `vi`, I passed the same coordinates (`vi.x` and `vi.y`) for a popup dialog criation (dialog `dial`), associated a layout `lay`, and under it has several buttons.

When I've positioned the popup, with the same `x`, `y` of the button, it does it correctly, but with a slight right and down shift, that I can't find any explanation.

PS: I positioned exactly the same place as the button, just to make the below image clear.

Here the dummy code. (It's working in a real app, but I've reduced for clarity):

```
fun openDialog(xPos: Float, yPos:Float) {
    ...
    val dial = Dialog(this)   // this is the context
    val win = dial.window
    val wlp = win.attributes
    wlp.apply {
        gravity = Gravity.TOP or Gravity.LEFT
        x = xPos
        y = yPos
      }
    win.attributes = wlp
    var lay = RelativeLayout(cx)
    ..... 
    dial.setContentView(
       lay, ViewGroup.LayoutParams(150,500))
    dial.show()
}
```

I've tried many things: `horizontalMargin` and `verticalMargin` in window attributes (`dial.window.attributes`), `padding`, `x`, `y` and `gravity` in layout `lay`

Nothing works!

**PS 1:** My main layout is full screen. Even the battery status is hidden. So the screen has the exact size of screen size.

**PS 2:** All my views and widgets are programatically created without XML.

Here is the scheme:

[image: Scheme]

Comment: If you set the `Window`'s background drawable to a transparent `ColorDrawable`, that should fix it, I believe. Actually, any color should work, IIRC, but it will show through if your root `View` is transparent. You can't just set the background to null, unfortunately, 'cause it uses a default if you pass null, and you're stuck with that odd padding/inset again.

Comment: [Mile M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2850651/mike-m), I will try it and after I will comment here.

Comment: Amazing! The displacement it's much smaller with transparent background. I've used `win.setBackgroundDrawable(....)` where `win` is the window linked to the dialog. +/- 3 times smaller!

Comment: I ran a quick test after I'd commented here, and it lined up exactly for me, to the pixel. That is, there was no displacement at all. Are you sure you don't have any margins or paddings or drawables with "gaps" in your final content?

Comment: [Mike M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2850651/mike-m)  You've saved my life. If you post the answer is the right answer! It seems to me as a gap because it was transparent. When I've used a drawable with white color the gap was 0! I just don't understand why it solves the problem.

Comment: Hmm, that is interesting. I don't think that was the case, for me, but I was using a really basic setup, and only did a couple of test cases. Well, I'm glad we got something working for you, but I'd like to be more certain of the exact cause and behavior before I post an answer. I'll try to do some more testing and research later on, when I get a chance. Cheers!